# Python Predefined Auto-Import in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

Here is an import example from [Selenium Python Bindings Library Documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

These two imports are used a lot. Is there a way to do the following:

- Define "from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By" as auto-import suggestion somewhere
- Have auto-complete suggestions after typing "By." even without importing
- Selecting a suggestion given after typing "By." creates an import as in the first code block?

Answer (score 1):

I use yasnippet for a similar thing:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# contributor: jpkotta
# name: from __future__ import ...
# key: future
# --
from __future__ import print_function, division, unicode_literals, absolute_import
```

You can make a pretty simple command to do this if you don't want to bother with yasnippet:

```
(defun insert-foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((str "foo"))
    (save-excursion
      (save-restriction
        (widen)
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (unless (search-forward-regexp (concat "^" (regexp-quote str)) nil t)
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (while (and (looking-at (concat "^" comment-start))
                    (not (eobp)))
            (forward-line 1))
          (insert str))))))
```

This is smart enough to skip comments at the beginning of the buffer and is idempotent, but will not run automatically.  You could write a command to search for another string "By." and run the insert command if it's found, and then add it to e.g. `python-mode-hook` or `before-save-hook`.